# Automate Data transformation using cologne-phonetic Algorithm

Tags: python, t-sql, openrefine

**Existing Process:** Team gets data in Excel spreadsheet and then the spreadsheet data is passed through OpenRefine (called GoogleRefine earlier) and does Key Collision basically to correct data with similar names into one as per below screen shot.

In this sample spreadsheet data, two such rows have **Babulal** and **Babu lal** and after this data is run through OpenRefine, Both the rows will have only only value **Babu Lal**

**OpenRefine**

[image: [Screenshot of RAW data and data after Transformation]]

**Before and After Transformation of Data**

[image: Before and After Transformation of Data]

The algorithm used to transform this data in OpenRefine uses **Key Collision Method with Keying function as cologne-phonetic**

**Help:** I need to automate this process and this data will be stored in MS SQL Server Datawarehouse and hence I am open for suggestions/methods that can be applied on Excel data or after loading this data to SQL Server or Python scripts that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Cologne phonetic module on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/cologne-phonetics/

Note, however, that human review is a key part of the OpenRefine cluster review process. All phonetic keyers produce false positives with their clustering. In your examples above, it's arbitrary which string OpenRefine will be picked as the target from the pair. With a large number of matches, it'll pick the highest frequency candidate, if one exists, but there's still no guarantee that that will be the correct candidate.